# A name for layered directed graph as in a fully-connected neural network

Tags: graph-theory, neural-networks

Is there a common name for the type of directed acyclic graph structure used in fully-connected neural networks?
E.g.

[image]

To be specific, I'm speaking of a directed graph, $G=(V,E)$, whose vertices can be partitioned into $k$ non-empty disjoint sets $V_1, ..., V_k$ such that $V = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^k V_i$ and $E = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} V_i\times V_{i+1}$.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a common name for this. I would call it a `complete layered directed graph` or something. A neural network with two layers is called a `complete bipartite graph`.

Answer (score 3):

In the book [Planning Algorithms by Steven M. LaValle](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/), there is another name for that graph on page 65.

> A layered graph is a graph that has its vertices
>   partitioned into a sequence of layers, and its edges are only permitted to connect
>   vertices between successive layers.

Although this is more general than the "fully-connected" case.

In addition, I found the name to be quite useless to find other literature. It seems to only give results on a different concept, [layered graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing).

Comment: Using your definition we see every digraph $G=(V,E)$ can be partitioned into the layers $\{\{v\}:v\in V\}$ also since $E=\bigcup_{(u,v)\in E(G)}\{u\}\times \{v\}$ its edges only connect vertices between successive layers. Thus all digraphs are "layered graphs" using "Steven M. LaValle" terminology i.e. that definition is essentially useless.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. At least not up to my knowledge.

If you only have an input layer and an output layer, the graph $G = (V, E)$ is [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). The "bi" means you can make two sets of nodes $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$ with $V_1 \cup V_2 = V$ and all edges $(v_1, v_2) \in E: v_1 \in V_1 \land v_2 \in V_2$.

The more general term is $k$-partite (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph)). A neural network with $k$ layers (including input and output) is $k$-partite (one also says it is "multipartite").

edit: I've just realized that this is not the exact class you want. The set of all $k$-partite graphs contains all neural networks with $k$ layers, but not only simple multilayer perceptron architectures. It also contains architectures like [DenseNets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993) and more. But I guess "$k$-partite directed graph" is as close as you get without saying "multilayer perceptron graph structure" or something similar.

edit: Thanks to [Chiel ten Brinke](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53989/chiel-ten-brinke), I've realized that $k=2$ for any layered network (without residual connections). Just put all even-numbered layer nodes in one set and all odd-numbered layer nodes in another set.

Comment: This is not correct. The example of the OP is also bipartite, as it is 2-colorable. The generalization of k-partite has to do with more colors being needed for a valid colorization. Look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-partiter_Graph

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke Thank you very much for this comment. While you are correct that it is also bipartite (and I didn't realize that before), I don't see where my post is (or was) wrong. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Any $k$-partite graph is also $k+1$ partite, isn't it?

Comment: Strictly speaking that is correct, but the intention of the answer was to give a characterizing name for the class of graphs described by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For any digraphs $A$ and $B$ a map $f$ is referred to as a full homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ iff there is a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ satisfying $\small \forall u,v\in V(A)((a,b)\not\in E(A)\implies (f(u),f(v))\not\in E(B))$, this is fairly common notation (e.g. here are several papers using this terminology [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.02690.pdf),[2](https://mast.queensu.ca/~ctardif/articles/ghss.pdf),[3](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7aba/33224720030ed489f8b136a9566d5a300769.pdf)), so naturally when there exists a full homomorphism from one digraph to another digraph then the first digraph is said to be fully homomorphic to the second one. Now with that said **the digraphs you are describing are exactly those that are fully epimorphic to directed paths**.

To see why note if any digraph $G=(V,E)$ has a surjective full homomosphism to any directed path $P=(U,R)$ where we have $U=\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$ and $R=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),\ldots (n-1,n)\}$ then there must exist a surjection $f:\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}\to V$ satisfying $(i,j)\in R\iff (f(i),f(j))\in E$ thus we know $\small E=\{(f(i),f(j)):(i,j)\in R\}=\bigcup_{(i,j)\in R}f^{-1}[\{i\}]\times f^{-1}[\{j\}]=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}f^{-1}[\{k\}]\times f^{-1}[\{k+1\}]$ where $f$ is a surjection and all the fibers $\small \{f^{-1}[\{1\}],f^{-1}[\{2\}],\ldots f^{-1}[\{n\}]\}=\text{coim}(f)$ must partition $V$.